Identifying and finding a charger and disk for the Acer Anyware K386s?
A few months ago, I was given an Acer Anyware K386s. It doesn't have a drive, and I wasn't given a charger. I thought I'd be able to find these components somewhere, but there are almost no mentions of the device anywhere on the internet. Those I found don't mention most its tech specs, let alone specifically the charger and drive it needs.

Reddit user trying to fix their floppy disk drive
Vogons user trying to fix weird scrolling behavior
An archive of a news post about the device from close to its release

There's a bit more out there, but this is almost everything to be found about the device on the internet. Does anyone have a lead on how I could get a charger and disk for it? What charger and disk does it even need?



As requested in the comments, here's a better  view of the charger port and its scale measured with calipers (it's 10mm in diameter; the shadow obscures my placement a bit). Unfortunately, I don't have a pinout and don't know how I'd figure it out.




The image is dark and there is no way to gauge its size without a measurement or something to compare against. Can you show the pin-out in a simple graphic, and maybe include the diameter of the plug hole?

By enhancing the contrast it looks to me like there are four pins in an arrangement roughly like ⊔, perhaps with the upper pair of pins further apart symmetrically. It's not possible to say for sure whether there is an overbar at the top.

@tripleee Added more images of the charger port, including a measurement of its diameter with calipers. I don't know the pinout or how to figure out what it is, unfortunately.

Thanks, so 10mm? That's larger than I thought from the initial image.

Yep, it's 10mm. Your description of the pin arrangement was correct as well; there are 4 pins arranged symmetrically about the vertical center, but the top two pins are slightly further apart than the bottom two pins.

May be a small detail, but chances are it's not a charger but just a power supply. Voltages and pinout unknown. And that looks like a bog standard 4-pin Mini-DIN Power connector (i.e. the pins are larger than on normal Mini-DINs). It looks identical in size to the PS/2 keyboard Mini-DIN connector.

Hard disc or floppy disc?

From quick googling - could this PC also named as "Acer Acros 325SE"? Looks similar, maybe this yieds more results. See https://www.ebay.com/itm/314978735901 - there you can see power adapter model and pin layout :)

From quick googling - could this PC also named as "Acer Acros 325SE"? Looks similar, maybe this yields more results. See ebay.com/itm/314978735901 - there on one image you can see power adapter model and pin layout.
/edit - I'll add part of image here/


In case the ebay link goes away: It says 5.5V / 3.9A and 8.5V / 2.35A both on the laptop underside and the charger. That would be consistent with the 4-connector plug (with probably two GND connections). I don't see an image with the pin layout, though.

On the charger underside, on yellow sticker. It includes DC SENSE and SYS. IN USE pins however, it is not clear (to me), how to use those pins..

Ah, so it's actually 5 pins... it looks like one of the "keys" visible at the edge the black socket shown by the OP then must have a metal tongue somewhere, that should be easy to verify, and would be an indication that it is indeed the same charger connection. My guess is that DC SENSE is used by the laptop to detect the presence of a charger, and SYS. IN.USE is used by the charger to detect that the laptop is drawing power (whatever the signalling scheme is).

@dirkt GND can be metal barrel itself, not pins. I would start with 5.5V (DC+) only - does it wake computer up? (This was not recommendation, in case you burn your Acer down!)

This looks like a match! This wordpress article and a few other links out there name both of these models as though they refer to the same machine. The pictures on this page are identical as well, except for only the model print. From what I can tell, Acer made a mid-range Acros line of laptops and re-branded them later?
I'll pick up one of these chargers!

Coming back to confirm, this charger came in today and it worked! If it helps anyone in the future, I had to remove the battery to get it to power on; the adapter's "~" indicator light would otherwise flicker when plugged in.

Partial answer:
Quick googling finds something for the Acer Anyware 386s (no K):
A website, with images of a very short manual, including a picture of the power adapter, and an explanation of connectors on the motherboard.
Judging from the image, it seems to be different from the K386s, but maybe it is similar enough to give some hints. In particular I'd compare the motherboard to the diagram above, and see how similar it is.
The website seems to have recent updates, including the contact page, so maybe you can ask for specific data on the charger (should be written on it), and possibly the web site owner can measure the voltages on the charger connector.
I would guess the charger is proprietary, so it really could be anything.
